# Is there a way to access a field/variable of a child class from the base class? Does it even make sense?

Tags: c#, php

(I am kind of new to C# so please forgive me if my question makes anyone laugh :) ).
I have a 'database' class which has a method `public bool Create()`. And 'user' class which has a field `string table_name = "user_table"` and it inherits the 'database' class. Is there a way to access `user.table_name` from the 'create' method of 'database' class? I am coming from php where you can use the keyword `static::$variable_name` from base class and it returns the value of that variable which is in the child class. For example:

```
    class A{
        public static function func(){
            $a = static::$variable_in_child_class; // calling the variable that is in child class
            print $a;
        }
    }

    class B extends A{
        public static $variable_in_child_class= "some value"; // variable in B class
    }

    $b = new B(); // object of type B
    $b->func();   // prints "some value"
```

Can i do anything similar in c#? Like:

```
    class database{
        public bool Create(){
            string table_name = //get the table name from child class
        }        
    }

    class user : database{
        public string table_name = "user_table";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user u = new user();
        u.create(); // calls create method from base without passing any argument
    }
```

Comment: You can create the variable table_name in your database class and then use it in your create method. Then, you can write every inheritance overriding the table_name string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to implement constructors for your classes:

```
class database
{
    public database()
    {
        //Parameterless constructor, should you need it.
    }
    public database(string table_name)
    {
        var tablename = table_name; //Initialization logic goes here
    }
}
```

Then your `user` class can call the base constructor as such:

```
class user: database
{
    public static string table_name = "user_table";

    public user() : base(table_name) { }

}
```

Which in turn gives the desired result:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user u = new user();
        u.create(); // calls create method from base without passing any argument
    }
```